# Obtain data that was printed to console (via NSLog) - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a custom framework with me that I have used and integrated into my project. That framework has some NSLog methods (which isn't exposed by the way) implemented in it that prints data into the console while the app is running.
I have a requirement such that I have to take that printed data and load it into a tableview and show it on screen in the app.
How do i go on about it ? I googled a lot but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done via Apple System Log, here is link with blogpost about it:

https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/accessing-the-ios-system-log/